# Buildbot: cannot filter out compilation warnings

Tags: buildbot

I'm trying to integrate into my buildbot process the feature to suppress specific compilation warnings.
Here what I did:

1) created the file with the warning exections, sample line below:

```
deps/include/linux/sofia-sip-1.12/sofia-sip/su_tag.h : .*
```

2) added to the Compile Step the following:

```
suppressionFile= <path_to> + "/buildbot-warnings-exceptions",
```

here the full buildstep for a better reference:

```
build_4_core = Compile (
    command        = ["make", "-j4"],
    warnOnWarnings = True,
    haltOnFailure  = True,
    workdir        = nr.vdk20_build_root,
    suppressionFile= nr.vdk20_build_root + "/buildbot-warnings-exceptions",
    name           = "make_j4" )
```

3) restarted the buildmaster

Unfortunately it seems the warning are not filtered out :(
As an example, here the warning line, still present in the compile step logs and warnings list:

> deps/include/linux/sofia-sip-1.12/sofia-sip/su_tag.h:206:25: warning:
>   unused parameter ‘p’ [-Wunused-parameter]

Tried several tweek of the file content but with no luck

What I'm I doing wrong?

Just to complete the picture:

Buildmaster: running on a gentoo server 64bit
Buildbot version: 0.8.8
Twisted version: 12.3.0

Buildslave : running on a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
Buildslave version: 0.8.5
Twisted version: 11.1.0

Comment: Can you put the complete command you are trying to execute in your compile step?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the command manually in the slave machine to see if warnings are filtered in the output?

Comment: @sk11 edited the post: I added the full buildstep, does that answer your question?

Comment: @hithwen: how can I execute manually the command to filter out warnings? I'm expecting that is the master/slave to make the filtering out of the listed warnings

Comment: In the stdio traces you should see which command was executed, if you execute that command manually what do you get? ( I may be wrong, I've never used compile step)